# Visual Studio Code, tslint and virtual machine

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using Visual Studio Code on my computer to develop a project (angular). The files of my project are located on a virtual machine.

Visual Studio Code works fine, I can edit my files without any problem but I can't see tslint errors. I would like to fix all tslint error I see by using "ng lint" command on my VM (via Putty) in Visual Studio Code.

When I'm trying to launch commands into the Visual Studio Code terminal, I've got errors :

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\192.168.0.141\Work\MyProject> ng lint
ng : Le terme «ng» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès
est correct et réessayez.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ ng build
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

or by using this command

```
./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

// it opens a file inside notepad...

If I run these commands through Putty, it works.

The goal is to use lint command to fix every files of my project (or maybe, do it by modules). I'm little bit confused and I don't know what I've to do.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much

EDIT :

```
Info  - 15:21:37] vscode-tslint: Cannot read tslint configuration - 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '\\192.168.0.141\work\work\myProject\src\app\testModule\services
```

The path is not good, where can I change this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The path is not good, where can I change this ?

Try changing the `tslint.configFile` Visual Studio Code setting.  You can find it by going to File -> Preferences -> Settings and typing the name in the search box.

Comment: Ah great ! Now my code is underline when there is a lint error :) Thank  you ! Do you know if it's possible to fix all lint errors by a command in Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: Click a lint error in the "Problems" panel, click the light-bulb icon that appears next to your code, and "Fix all auto-fixable problems".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly :)